# How to save an image to a customized filepath in django admin?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upload images to specific folders I select. the model code is as below:

```
class PhotosTags(models.Model):
    Tag_name = models.CharField('Tag Name', max_length=100, default='NA', unique=True)
    Description = models.TextField('Tag Description', max_length=200, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tags'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
        ordering = ['Date_created']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Tag_name)

class Photos(models.Model):
    Name = models.TextField('Photo Name', max_length=200, blank=True)
    Tag = models.ForeignKey(PhotosTags, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    filepath = 'Gallery'
    Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=filepath, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Photos'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
        ordering = ['Date_uploaded']

pre_save.connect(upload_photo, sender=Photos)
```

Here each tag has its own folder. The function I want to realize is, when I upload an image, I can select a specific tag (through selection of "Tag") and then this image can be uploaded to that folder. I tried use: `signals` to change the `filepath` but failed. The code i wrote is:

```
def upload_photo(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    tardir = instance.Tag.Tag_name
    instance.filepath = 'Gallery'+'/'+tardir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by sending upload_to path with a function.

```
import os

def path_generator(instance, filename):
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))
    file_dir = f"your_desired_path.{extension}"
    return file_dir

class Photos(models.Model):
    Name = models.TextField('Photo Name', max_length=200, blank=True)
    Tag = models.ForeignKey(PhotosTags, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
  
    Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_generator, blank=False)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Photos'
    verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
    ordering = ['Date_uploaded']
```

Comment: Because the "Tag" in "Photos" will be used in the path, I don't think your code works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can get Tag from instance.Tag, instance is sending to the function.

Comment: hmmm, I misunderstood your code. It finally works, Thanks a lot!